# can't send messages and $username isn't displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I made a chat service in php. When you get to the chat, it says "Welcome, --Username--." My problem is I added a login field, now I can't send messages and the username isn't displayed. I've looked everywhere but it seems since my code is so "unique", nothing seems to be helping. --i didn't make this all on my own, I used someone else's code for the login and someone's code for the service itself.

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo isset($_SESSION['login']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
      header('LOCATION:admin.php'); die();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <title>Login</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password'){
          $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:admin.php'); die();
        } {
          echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username and Password do not match.</div>";
        }
        if($username === 'admon' && $password === 'password'){
            $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:admin.php'); die();
          } {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username and Password do not match.</div>";
          }
          
      }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('LOCATION:login.php'); die();
    }

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    
     
        //Simple exit message
        $logout_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='left-info'>User <b class='user-name-left'>". $_SESSION['name'] ."</b> has left the chat session.</span><br></div>";
        file_put_contents("log.html", $logout_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
         
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: login.php"); //Redirect the user
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
 
        <title>English Pricks</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Group Chat." />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $username['username']; ?></b>&period; &nbsp;<a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S2O4y2z_8Yu_mibQQGEU4E9pHdeckPfo5pI7FtM0YrI/edit" target="_blank">Image Dump&period;&period;&period;</a></p>
                <p>Emoji's &#8594;&nbsp;</p>
                <button id="emoji-button" style="border: none;"></button>
                &nbsp;
                <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Leave</a></p>
            </div>
 
            <div id="chatbox">
            <?php
            if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
                $contents = file_get_contents("log.html");          
                echo $contents;
            }
            ?>
            </div>
 
            <form name="message" action="">
                <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" style="outline: none;" spellcheck="true"/>
                <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="&#8593;" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="emoji.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var picker = new EmojiButton();
        var button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
          picker.showPicker(button);
          picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
          document.querySelector('#usermsg').value += emoji;
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $.trim($("#usermsg").val());
    if(clientmsg.length >= 1){ // Prevents Spamming the Enter Key
        $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});             
        $("#usermsg").val("");
    }else{
        
    }
    return false;
}); 
                function loadLog() {
                    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height before the request
 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "log.html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div
 
                            //Auto-scroll           
                            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                }
 
                setInterval (loadLog, 1000);

                $("#exit").click(function () {
                    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?");
                    if (exit == true) {
                    window.location = "index.php?logout=true";
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `$username['username']`? Did you mean `$username` or `$_POST['username']`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes, I meant $username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **login.php** file `else` was missing in `if` blocks and in order to see **username** you should add it to `$_SESSION` in the same way as you did with
`$_SESSION['login']`, cause i don't see anything else which can serve as temp storage in provided code. Another issue is that you placed `header()` function with login and password check right inside html code. This will trigger **warning** on a runtime **that headers were already sent**. In order to avoid that place your checking code in the top of the file and also check if there are no spaces before or after `<?php` php opening tag.

Example of fixed **login.php** file you can find below.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  function setSessionData($name, $value) {
    $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
  }

  function redirectWithData($username = '') {
    setSessionData('login', true);
    setSessionData('username', $username);
    header('Location:admin.php'); 
    die();
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header('Location:admin.php'); die();
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username']; $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password'){
      redirectWithData($username);
    } elseif($username === 'admon' && $password === 'password'){
      redirectWithData($username);
    } else  {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username and Password do not match.</div>";
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
     <title>Login</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

On admin page you can then display username
`Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>`

Regarding `admin.php` functionality. Logic for adding messages according to JavaScript code located in **post.php** file.

`$.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});`

So, why its adding or not adding it is hard to answer for obvious reasons )

And btw, in your logout logic in **admin.php** file change
`window.location = "index.php?logout=true";` -> `window.location = "?logout=true";` it will fallback to the same page on which you already have redirect logic.

Comment: yep that worked, thanks!

for the **post.php** i had to add ```$_SESSION['username'];``` to it inorder for it to send texts